# User.ReadBasic.All scope not granted, v2

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to request the following 3 scopes for oauth from the v2 Azure directory: user.read, user.readbasic.all, calendars.readwrite.

My authorization GET request is

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?'
+ '&client_id=myclientid'
+ '&response_type=code'
+ `&redirect_uri=myredirecturl`
+ '&response_mode=query'
+ '&scope=user.read%20user.readbasic.all%20calendars.readwrite'
+ '&prompt=consent';
```

Notice I've ruled out having changed consent type since the last authorization was made.

I successfully get a code, and exchange that for a token:

```
axios.post(
'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token',
querystring.stringify(
  {
    client_id: my_client_id,
    client_secret: my_app_secret,
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code,
    scope: 'user.readbasic.all user.read calendars.readwrite',
    redirect_uri: my_redirect_url
  },
  null,
  null,
  { encodeURIComponent: s => encodeURI(s) }
)
```

);

1. I am not seeing any consent message for `user.readbasic.all` on login
2. I am not receiving `User.ReadBasic.All` in the response for the scope of the token I'm rewarded.
3. I am receiving user.read and calendars.readwrite

**Update**
I Believe i'm narrowing down the problem to changing scopes or tenant type. Although I have prompt=consent as a param, I am not getting the user.readbasic.all scope on my personal account. When I send the authorization link to others in organization tenants, they get the full list of permissions. Why are there two different permission pages for different users? Two screenshots:
[image: org tenant]
[image: personal tenant]

Comment: Did you add delegated permissions `user.readbasic.all `in that AADv2 App?

Comment: yes I have done that at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/

Comment: Try to use `https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fcalendars.readwirte%20
https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read%20
https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.readbasic.all` in the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stringify()` method is converting your object into `application/json`. This is incorrect, it should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

For details on how to do this with Axios, see [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/362#issuecomment-351254363).

Also, personal accounts (MSAs) can't "Read all users' basic profiles". As a "personal" account, there is only one user associated.

Comment: Personal accounts _can't_ read "all users' basic profiles". It's a personal account, there is only one user in the account.

Comment: Marc's point about personal accounts solved my question. 
Because I was granted other scopes, I don't have reason at this time to believe stringify was the cause of any issues